# Interpreting scipy.stats: ks_2samp and mannwhitneyu give conflicting results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've encountered conflicting results between [`ks_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) and [`mannwhitneyu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) while trying to compare two empirical distributions, particularly when specifying the "alternative" keyword argument. Per their respective docstrings, my understanding is that both share the same definition of alternative hypothesis. For example, given two samples X and Y, `alternative='greater'` denotes the alternative hypothesis that X is greater than Y, and the returned p-value represents the likelihood of the resultant test statistic if both distributions were the same. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the toy example below suggests this definition is reversed for the mannwhitneyu test.

Generating two different samples:

```
import numpy as np

N = 100000
x = np.exp(np.random.normal(np.log(1), size=N))
y = np.exp(np.random.normal(np.log(3), size=N))
```

[Sample distributions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPf6Y.png)

Running the two tests:

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp, mannwhitneyu

print(ks_2samp(x, y, alternative='greater'))
print(mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='greater'))
```

Yields:

> Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.41866, pvalue=0.0)
>
> MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=2188790813.0, pvalue=1.0)

And the opposite:

```
print(ks_2samp(x, y, alternative='less'))
print(mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='less'))
```

Yields:

> Ks_2sampResult(statistic=-0.0, pvalue=1.0)
>
> MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=2188790813.0, pvalue=0.0)

Given the wisespread usage of these functions I assume this comes down to my own misunderstanding. If someone could help clarify why they results are reversed I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KS test will (assuming `less`) test for the $H_1$ that the CDF of `x` lies below that of `y`. On the other hand, the MW  (assuming `less`) will test for the $H_1$ that the location shift is less than 0. The results reported are perfectly aligned with that as they indeed suggest that "*$x$ is smaller than $y$*". The KS fails to reject its null hypothesis in favour of the alternative that the CDF of `x` lies below that of `y`, while MW does reject it in favour of the alternative that `x` is shifted to the left of `y`.

Comment: Ah, so is it fair to say that for unimodal distributions (with similar spread) the two are more or less opposite? In the sense that a location shift less than zero would actually yield an increase in the 'height' of the CDF?

Comment: Yes, I tried to expand on it a bit more, I think that especially for the MW the `less` (or `greater`) is not super-clear as to where the shift is.

Comment: Super helpful - thank you!